# Create edgelist from adjacency matrix in a massive dataset

Tags: r, network-programming

Let's say I have the following sample data with some 2 million rows:

```
dt <- data.table(event_id=as.character(rep(letters[1:26],80000)),person_id=as.character(rep(letters[1:26],80000)), organizer_id = as.character(rep(letters[1:26],800000)))
```

In reality there are far more unique event_ids, person_ids, and organizer_ids than 26.  I construct the adjacency df like so:

```
adjacency_df <- dt %>%
  select('event_id', 'person_id', 'organizer_id') %>%
  melt('event_id', value.name = 'person_id') %>%
  dcast(person_id~person_id, fun.aggregate = n_distinct, value.var = 'event_id')
```

Next, I am trying to go from the adjacency_df to an edgelist.  I can't figure out an approach, however, that scales well.

This code

```
adjacency_matrix <- crossprod(table(rep(dt$event_id, 2), unlist(dt[, c('event_id', 'person_id')])))
```

Returns the error

```
Error in table - attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

This code hangs for more than 30 minutes on the real dataset, and doesn't actually generate a clean edge-list on the sample dataset above.

```
edge_df_2 <- data.frame(name = paste(rownames(adjacency_df)[col(adjacency_df)], colnames(adjacency_df)[row(adjacency_df)], sep="-"),
          val = c(t(adjacency_df)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using the library(wNetwork) and doing:

```
edge <- adjacency.to.edgelist(as.matrix(adjacency_df))
```

returns the error that I don't have an adjacency matrix.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `which` function which will give you indicies of the non zero element from the adjacency matrix
like:

```
which(ad.matrix != 0)
```

Comment: I don't see where to go from there.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. If you have a binary adjacency matrix a.mat, which(a.mat == 1, arr.ind = TRUE) will give you the index of non zero elements. so basically a list of links. Not sure this is what you are looking for, only a suggestion.

Comment: Let me try that.  A list of links is what I was looking for